# ./mvnw stuck at "[INFO] Scanning for projects..." on azure vm

Tags: azure, maven, jhipster

I have cloned a jhipster porject in an Azure virtual machine and tried to lauch it using ./mvnw

However, despite working on my pc, this command does not seem to do so on this vm and remains stuck at "[INFO] Scanning for projects..." until it is killed by the vm:


 $ ./mvnw

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Killed


With -X, I get:


$ ./mvnw -X

Apache Maven 3.6.2 (...)

Maven home: /home/ecomg219/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.6.2-bin/795eh28tki48bv3l67maojf0ra/apache-maven-3.6.2

Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8

OS name: "linux", version: "5.0.0-1023-azure", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api

...

[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/ecomg219/.m2/repository

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.ecom.app:ecom:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)

[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]

[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix spring-boot from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]

Killed


Any clue about where it can come from or how to correct it is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried to give something like `./mvnw clean package` ?

Comment: It goes a bit further but still gets stuck a few lines later...

Comment: [INFO] Building Ecom 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT    
[INFO] ------[ jar ]-----    
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> ...    
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]    
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]    
Killed

Comment: can you show the full log file output ? Or show a real example where it fails as you show it here?